# Oracle EXAData 19c - Shared pool memory utilization is not going down even no process are running

Tags: java, oracle, database-design, exadata

Using Oracle Exadata 19c for RDS database. We are running numerous queries from java application and also calling many stored procedures. We identified that as the number of processes/sessions are increasing , shared memory pool utilization is started going up. But once processes are completed and sessions are closed/vanish, still shared memory pool utilization is not coming down which was not the case in previous oracle versions.

We need to manually flush the shared memory pool to bring down the SM utilization back to 0.

Does anyone facing same issue or do we have any configuration in place that we are missing ? Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your machine is under memory pressure, it would be unwise to release memory back the OS just for the sake of doing so.  Flushing the shared pool is generally a bad idea unless you have a specific need to do so (eg memory leak, bug etc), but other than that, you *want* the SGA to be "full" all the time.

Full means buffer cache will as efficient as possible, library cache will reduce parsing etc...A full SGA is a good thing.

Comment: Hey Connor, Thanks for answer, But if SGA is going full then applications are loosing connections also new triggered cloud native tasks are not connecting to db and saying that shared pool utilization is full and cannot connect to database. I assume that Its not getting buffer space to initialize and plan the query execution. 

Hence we are releasing the SGA utilization and they it kickstart connecting/working the application. Looks processes are not releasing the SGA used even after completing.

Comment: That means its time to call Support, because no matter how full the SGA is, people should never be booted off or be unable to connect. Failed connections will most likely create incident trace files and write to the alert log.  Start there and log an SR